# Updating a Progress Bar within the Status Bar

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm trying to figure out how to incorporate a progress bar within the status bar to show how much processing is completed. Below is my example of updating the progress bar (not sure if this is the correct way or not)

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = ToolStripProgressBar1.Value + 2
    If ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = 0
        ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = ToolStripProgressBar1.Value + 2
        Timer1.Enabled = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Here is the code within the button.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1Run.Click
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Processing..."
    Timer1.Enabled = True

    'more code to be inserted here        

End Sub
```

What I'm not sure is how to update the progress bar based on the amount of code you have and once the processing is complete, update the `ToolStripStatusLabel1` to show "Processing...Complete!".

Comment: I guess the other site is probably best fit for my question. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, you would use the `PerformStep()` method to update the ProgressBar.  This action will increment the value of the ProgressBar by the value entered in the `Step` property.

The ProgessBar also has a `Maximum` property to determine when the progress is at 100%.  That is, if the Maximum=100 and the Value=100, the ProgressBar should show full.

Typical setup:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1Run.Click
  ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum = 100
  ToolStripProgressBar1.Step = 2
  ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = ToolStripProgressBar1.Minimum
  ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Processing..."
  Timer1.Start()
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
  ToolStripProgressBar1.PerformStep()
  If ToolStripProgressBar1.Value >= ToolStripProgressBar1.Maximum Then
    Timer1.Stop()
    ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Completed"
    ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = ToolStripProgressBar1.Minimum
  End If
End Sub
```

A timer is usually an odd type of measurement for showing code progression.  A ProgressBar usually is used with a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to show the progress of your code.

Comment: Thank you. I will take a look at your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

```
If ToolStripProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
```

Are you sure your value will ever get to "exactly" 100?
 Maybe

```
If ToolStripProgressBar1.Value >= 100 Then
```

Or is 100 some [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_%28programming%29)?

EDIT: It really depends on the code you intend on running. The progress bar is just a visual indicator for the user that you have to set based on a particular process. If you just want it to display to show something is happenning (similar to an hour glass icon) this should work.

Somewhere you need to Set the timer.enabled to false and cleanup the progress bar.

Comment: Well I guess the magic number could be higher or lower, dependent on how long time takes to say, as an example copy a 1G text file from location 1 to location 2 or based on the amount of code you are processing.